# Dead references in services list

Tags: server, email, services

This question is a follow up to 
[Strange symbols in front of suspicious services](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086785/strange-symbols-in-front-of-suspicious-services/1087085#1087085)

I have the following are dead service references om my AWS EC2 instance that is running as an email exchange for my own domain.

```
UNIT                           LOAD      ACTIVE   SUB     DESCRIPTION
ΓùÅ auditd.service             not-found inactive dead    auditd.service
ΓùÅ connman.service            not-found inactive dead    connman.service
ΓùÅ console-screen.service     not-found inactive dead    console-screen.service
ΓùÅ display-manager.service    not-found inactive dead    display-manager.service
ΓùÅ exim4.service              not-found inactive dead    exim4.service
ΓùÅ fcoe.service               not-found inactive dead    fcoe.service
ΓùÅ iscsi-shutdown.service     not-found inactive dead    iscsi-shutdown.service
```

I have been assured that these cannot and has not harmed my server in any way. Still, I don't want to leave them dangling since this email server is my child and I can't stand it wearing torn clothes.

The task might seem trivial but I would please like advise on what action to take to resolve this?